# Serve Gatsby blog site in sub directory with Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, gatsby, netlify

I'm new to gatsby and netlify and I'm having a problem.

I have a domain called example.com. It has an index.html file, which is a static html file. I want to create a subfolder named blog here and put the blog I created with gastby into it.

```
example.com -> run index.html
example.com/blog -> run gatsby blog inside blog folder
```

When I do this and try to build in netlify, I get an error. The error message is: "**failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 254**".

My netlify.toml is:

```
[build]
  base    = ""
  publish = "public"
  command = "npm run build"
```

My package.json is:

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "gatsby develop",
   "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-pattern public .",
   "format": "prettier --write '{gatsby-*.js,src/**/*.{js,jsx,json,css}}'",
   "develop": "gatsby develop",
   "start": "npm run develop",
   "build": "run-p build:**",
   "build:app": "npm run clean && gatsby build --prefix-paths && npm run move",
   "move": "cd public && mkdir blog | mv * blog",
   "deploy": "yarn build && cp now.json public/ && cd public && now alias $(now) hkucuk.com",
   "dry": "yarn build && cp now.json public/ && cd public && now"
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where you able to find a good solution for this problem?